# Count instances of first word in column Oracle SQL using SUBSTR and REGEXP_COUNT

Tags: sql, oracle, count, substr

Using Oracle SQL, I have a column of strings called "title" in a table called OBJECT. Words are separated by spaces.

I want to write a query **count how many titles have the same first word as other titles** in the table. I want to output the word, and a count of how many entries begin with that word as FIRSTWORD, WORD_COUNT. E.G.

```
FIRSTWORD     WORD_COUNT
Word1   23
Word2   15
```

I am using both SUBSTR and INSTR to get the first word of each entry, and regexp_count to try and count the number of times it appears. So far, I can get it to output a list of the first words, but my count is always 0:

```
SELECT 
(SUBSTR(title, 0, INSTR(title, ' ')-1)) AS FIRSTWORD, 
(REGEXP_COUNT(title, INSTR(title, ' ')-1)) AS WORD COUNT 
FROM OBJECT GROUP BY title;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [subquery](http://psoug.org/reference/with.html) should do the trick.

```
WITH firstwords AS (
  SELECT (SUBSTR(OBJECT.title, 0, INSTR(OBJECT.title, ' ')-1)) AS WORD
  FROM OBJECT)
SELECT word, count(word)
FROM firstwords
GROUP BY word;
```

Comment: Thankyou! That was perfect. I didn't know how to do this properly.

Answer (score 2):

FYI.  You don't actually need a subquery.  You can do the calculation at one level:

```
select SUBSTR(OBJECT.title, 0, INSTR(OBJECT.title, ' ')-1)) AS WORD, count(*)
from OBJECT
group by SUBSTR(OBJECT.title, 0, INSTR(OBJECT.title, ' ')-1)) ;
```